# Pass prop from Consumer -> Provider context and access it outside of Provider render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called "Home," which is the home page for my website. This Home component uses a context called "ProductContext" in order to access all the products in a data.js file. The thing is, I'm going to have multiple *data.js files for each page of my website, so I went to tell the context file which page "I'm on" so it accesses the corresponding *data.js file.

"Home" component:

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    page: "Home",
  };

  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="py-2">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <Title title="PRODUCTS" className="pl-5" />
            <div
              className="row no-gutters "
              style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}
            >
              <ProductConsumer page={"Home"}>
                {(value) => {
                  console.log(value);
                  return value.products.map((product) => {
                    return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
                  });
                }}
              </ProductConsumer>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

ProductContext:

```
render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          handleDetail: this.handleDetail,
          addToCart: this.addToCart,
          openModal: this.openModal,
          closeModal: this.closeModal,
          increment: this.increment,
          decrement: this.decrement,
          removeItem: this.removeItem,
          clearCart: this.clearCart,
          setPage: this.setPage,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

You can tell I tried a few things like passing it through props or through a function in the context. I'm sure I'm close but I can't figure out exactly how to do it. I've seen other examples where you call a Provider function, most commonly with "onClick" but this needs to happen when either the Home component or ProductContext is constructed or mounted so the Page component can pull the right data. What I mean:

```
//In Home Component

componentDidMount() {
   let context = this.context;
   context.setPage("Home");

}
```

Except of course this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very limited understanding of how contexts work. From this experience I guess I learned that contexts should really be looked as something that *provides* data, not something that takes data.

I resolved this issue by first sorting the data in the context into different arrays, and then passing the corresponding array to each page.